# How to check/remove an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(function(){

  $("#tags input").on({
    focusout : function() {
      var txt = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\+\-\.\#]/ig,''); // allowed characters
      if(txt) $("<span/>", {text:txt.toLowerCase(), insertBefore:this});
      this.value = "";
    },
    keyup : function(ev) {
      // if: comma|enter (delimit more keyCodes with | pipe)
      if(/(188|13|32)/.test(ev.which)){
        $(this).focusout();
      } else if (/(8)/.test(ev.which) && this.value == '' && $(this).prev("span").css('background-color')=="rgb(225, 0, 0)") {
        $(this).prev("span").remove();
      } else if (/(8)/.test(ev.which) && this.value == '') {
        $(this).prev("span").css('background-color', 'Red');
      }
    }
  });
  $('#tags').on('click', 'span', function() {
     $(this).remove(); 
  });

});
```

```css
#tags{
  float:right;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:5px;
  font-family:Arial;
}
#tags > span{
  cursor:pointer;
  display:block;
  float:right;
  color:#3e6d8e;
  background:#E1ECF4;
  padding:5px;
  padding-right:25px;
  margin:4px;
}
#tags > span:hover{
  opacity:0.7;
}
#tags > span:after{
 position:absolute;
 content:"×";
 border:1px solid;
 padding:2px 5px;
 margin-left:3px;
 font-size:11px;
}
#tags > input{
  direction: rtl;
  background:#eee;
  border:0;
  margin:4px;
  padding:7px;
  width:auto;
}
.autocomplete{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tags">
  <span>php</span>
  <span>html</span>
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" />
  <div class="autocomplete"></div>
</div>
```

I want to remove a tag either by pressing backspace button *(when the input is focused)* or by clicking on that tag. Now I'm talking about the first option. Also I need to set it a red background color first *(as "are you sure?" concept)*. Ok as you see, my fiddle sets it a red background color, but it doesn't remove it. what's wrong?

Comment: add a class instead. jQuery css() method returns computed style which is browser dependant, you shouldn't rely on it. Anyway, your code seems quite obvious to debug

Comment: As a side note, 225 != 255 ...

Comment: @A.Wolff Well what do you mean I cannot rely on it? how can I get the color of an element in all browsers? something like `if($(this).css("background-color")=="Red"){} ` is wrong?

Comment: You don't want to rely on any specific color computed by browser (does it return rgb color, string as set by inline style, or what???) but you want to check for element state. So for exemple, you can add a class to this element and check if this specific element has this class. Btw, you could then set style for this specific class...

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes I can use a class instead of using the current element's color to check element's state. but you know,  I've relied on element's color already for other tasks. Should I change all of them? `:-(` Isn't there any working approach which get element's color for all browsers?

Comment: @A.Wolff And why not write an answer?!! Please write one if you have some free time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have better to toggle a class and check for it, e.g:

```js
$(function() {

  $("#tags input").on({
    focusout: function() {
      var txt = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\+\-\.\#]/ig, ''); // allowed characters
      if (txt) $("<span/>", {
        text: txt.toLowerCase(),
        insertBefore: this
      });
      this.value = "";
    },
    keyup: function(ev) {
      // if: comma|enter (delimit more keyCodes with | pipe)
      if (/(188|13|32)/.test(ev.which)) {
        $(this).focusout();
      } else if (/(8)/.test(ev.which) && this.value == '' && $(this).prev("span").hasClass('toRemove')) { //<< check for class
        $(this).prev("span").remove();
      } else if (/(8)/.test(ev.which) && this.value == '') {
        $(this).prev("span").addClass('toRemove'); //<< add class
      } else {
        $(this).prevAll('.toRemove').removeClass('toRemove'); //<< remove class on keyup
      }
    }
  });
  $('#tags').on('click', 'span', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });

});
```

```css
#tags {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
#tags > span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  color: #3e6d8e;
  background: #E1ECF4;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  margin: 4px;
}
#tags > span:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#tags > span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "×";
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
#tags > input {
  direction: rtl;
  background: #eee;
  border: 0;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: auto;
}
.autocomplete {
  display: none;
}
#tags > span.toRemove {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tags">
  <span>php</span>
  <span>html</span>
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" />
  <div class="autocomplete"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you .. upvote .. but there is a small problem .. I think your code will be more user-friendly, if a red-color-tag be regular-color-tag right after writing something into the input .. *(not waiting until a new tag added)*

Comment: Now, write a character into that input, and then press *backspace* once, then both that character will be removed and the last tag will be red. I guess setting red color for last tag needs one more backspace when the input is empty...

Answer (score 1):

I built in a counter for you that checks the status of your keypress. If you press once the counter is 1 and if you press the second time it removes the element and is 0 again. I hope thats what you wanted. Check this:

```
$(function() {

  counter = 0;

  $("#tags input").on({
    focusout: function() {
      var txt = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\+\-\.\#]/ig, ''); // allowed characters
      if (txt) $("<span/>", {
        text: txt.toLowerCase(),
        insertBefore: this
      });
      this.value = "";
      $("#tags span").css('background-color', '#E1ECF4');
      counter = 0;
    },
    keyup: function(ev) {
      // if: comma|enter (delimit more keyCodes with | pipe)
      if (/(188|13|32)/.test(ev.which)) {
        $(this).focusout();
      } else if (/(8)/.test(ev.which) && this.value == '') {
        counter = counter + 1;
        if (counter == 1) {
          $(this).prev("span").css('background-color', 'Red');
        } else {
          $(this).prev("span").remove();
          counter = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  });
  $('#tags').on('click', 'span', function() {
    $(this).remove();
      $("#tags span").css('background-color', '#E1ECF4');
      counter = 0;
  });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4swtduae/7/

Comment: Yeah, now that's much better .. but it would be perfect if the red color goes away when you write anything except backspace in the input *(I mean it shouldn't wait until a new tag added to remove red color)*