# How can I check has the input been empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```js
  $("input").on('keyup', function(ev){
      if(/(8)/.test(ev.which) && this.value == ''){
        alert('when you pressed backspace, the input was empty already');
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

All I'm trying to do is implementing this:

> when you pressed "backspace", the input was empty already

Actually I don't know English very well, maybe the correct sentence is this:

> when you pressed "backspace", the input has been empty before your pressing

Ok, write a character into the input, then press backspace, what happens? Both that character will be removed and that alert will be shown. I need to set one step between them, I mean I need two separated backspace for those events.

One backspace for removing the last character, one backspace else for showing that alert. How can I do that?

Comment: ... why... that's like telling the user they pressed A when they press A...

Comment: @KevinB: Good old MS Word Paperclip comes to mind :)

Comment: @KevinB All I'm trying to do is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616516/how-to-check-remove-an-element/39617457?noredirect=1#comment66541764_39617457)

Comment: @KevinB btw, using `keydown` instead of `keyup` doesn't work correctly.

Comment: why not? if you don't know why it doesn't work fixing it would be like shooting wildly into the dark. I never suggested using keydown.

Comment: @KevinB In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3cxyrgu7/#update) I've used `keydown`, but the last tag will be red when you write something into the input.

Comment: and... why does that happen? does the event not trigger? is e.which not what you expected it to be? is the value not empty like you expected it to be? narrow down the problem. It doesn't work isn't an acceptable problem statement.

Comment: @KevinB well I know why it doesn't work as expected. when you remove the last character, the value of the input will be empty, that's the reason of also getting the last tag red. I can solve the problem by storing the value of input into a variable every time and check that variable. But I thought maybe a professional programmer has a better algorithm.

Comment: so, then, the problem is the .val() isn't giving you what you expected? Why isn't what you originally provided enough to solve your problem? Why won't keydown solve it?

Comment: @KevinB yes, the problem is `this.value == ''` .. it's *true* when it shouldn't be `:-)`

Comment: Not when you use keydown, which gets triggered *before* the value property gets updated.

Comment: @KevinB I don't know why honestly ..

Comment: ... keydown works. what's the confusion?

Comment: @KevinB Odd .. now yes, `keydown` works. But I've tested it already, it didn't work ..

Comment: @KevinB Well no ... `keydown` doesn't work always correctly . [see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XVL98.png), both the last tag is red and there is a character into that input.

Comment: fiddle or it didn't happen

Comment: @KevinB [see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8C9Nc.png) .. you just need to play with that input

Comment: right, i can recreate your issue by making it red correctly, and then adding letters again because you're not making it not red after. doesn't mean keydown isn't working, just means you didn't finish writing your code.

Comment: I can't get past the fact that you're using regex to test that the numeric value of `ev.which` is equal to `8`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event that you are looking for is `keydown`

```js
  $("input").on('keydown', function(ev){
      if(ev.which === 8 && this.value == ''){
        alert('when you pressed backspace, the input was empty already');
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

**UPDATE**
You can handle it with `class` as well:

```js
  $("input").on('keyup', function(ev){
      if(ev.which === 8 && this.value == '' && $(this).hasClass('empty-input')){
        $(this).removeClass('empty-input');
        alert('when you pressed backspace, the input was empty already');
      } else {
        if (this.value == '') {
          $(this).addClass('empty-input');
        }
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: upvote for correct answer but I must add I would hate to see this in any software I'd be using.

Comment: I agree with you, no one likes `alert` maybe it's just for test or learning. I won't do that on production.

Comment: Yes your code works for the example in my question., upvote, but sadly it doesn't work as expected for my [real purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616516/how-to-check-remove-an-element/39617457?noredirect=1#comment66541764_39617457)

Comment: @martin-aj could you explain more?

Comment: well you can take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616516/how-to-check-remove-an-element/39617457?noredirect=1#comment66541764_39617457

Comment: @Mehdi One unrelated question, where are you from? Your name looks like Iranian names, am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123897/discussion-between-mehdi-and-martin-aj).

Answer (score 2):

Use `keydown` event instead!

With `keyup`, value of the `input` is already cleared hence `value==''` will always be true.

```js
$("input").on('keydown', function(ev) {
  if (ev.which === 8 && this.value == '') {
    alert('when you pressed backspace, the input was empty already');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Yes your code works for the example in my question., upvote, but sadly it doesn't work as expected for my [real purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616516/how-to-check-remove-an-element/39617457?noredirect=1#comment66541764_39617457)